# 5 radio buttons fill up randomly?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, radio-button

Hi I am trying to make five buttons as you can see and I want a function when you push "click me" it will fill up the five button randomly.

It's like a random generator for stats for a game.

I don't know if I'm doing it all wrong but I think I need some other coding for this.

Can anyone that can help me?

This is what I have:

```
<button onclick='myFunction()'>click me</button>

<div id="demo">
<Input type = radio Name = r1> 
<Input type = radio Name = r2> 
<Input type = radio Name = r3> 
<Input type = radio Name = r4>
<Input type = radio Name = r5> 
</div>


<script type="text/javascript">

    function myFunction() {
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = '';
    var num = 3;
    var noOfButtons = Math.floor(Math.random() * num);
    console.log(noOfButtons);
    for (var i = 0; i < noOfButtons; i++) {

    var box = document.createElement();
        document.getElementById('demo');
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: What does "fell up" mean? Select?

Comment: I would guess that he means fill up...

Comment: You never assign any values to the buttons...

Comment: I kind of like "fell up" more..

Comment: The idea of radio buttons is that in a group they all have the same name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not exactly sure what your looking for. I threw this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/MwQMR/) together. Take a look and see if its what you're looking for.

```
<button id='button1'>click me</button>
<div id="demo">
    <input type='radio' id='r1'>
    <input type='radio' id='r2'>
    <input type='radio' id='r3'>
    <input type='radio' id='r4'>
    <input type='radio' id='r5'>
</div>
```

.

```
     var button1 = document.getElementById('button1');
     button1.onclick = function () {
         var noOfButtons = 5;
         var pick = Math.floor(Math.random() * noOfButtons) + 1;
         var radioBtn = document.getElementById('r' + pick);
         radioBtn.checked = true;
     }
```

[**[edit]**](http://jsfiddle.net/MwQMR/1)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help me but iam looking for where it is not just 1 button that get select one of the time but where it is random so ever time you push the "click me" i can get 2 or 4 button select as the same time. exemple: 1 "click me" O O - 2 "click me" O O O O

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're trying to do is randomly check a finite number of radios, in which case there's no need to set `demo`'s  html to ''. I added the class `myRadios` to the tags of your radios (just in case there are other radios on the page that you don't want to include in the random checking), and then used the following function:

```
function myFunction() {
    var radios = document.getElementsByClassName('myRadios');
    for (var i=0; i<radios.length; i++)
    {
        radios[i].checked = ( (Math.random()*10) > 5) ? true : false;
    }
}
```

Here is a a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/asifrc/r4cRK/). Let me know if this is the functionality you were looking for or if you have any questions about how it works :)